# Open sets taking the complement

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing a self study in real analysis everything was going fine until I stumbeled across. How can we deduce that we get closed set if the take the compelment now?

[image]

Comment: Closed sets are the complements of open sets. So, you can repeat the same proof that was done for the open set $G$ and $E$, using $F^c$ and $E^c$, where $F$ is closed in $X$ and $E$ is closed in $Y$.

Comment: Let me see if I got this straight. I tried proving it using another approach. Let $\mathcal{F}^c\subseteq X$. We say that $\mathcal{F}^c$ is open if and only iff $\forall x\in \mathcal{F}^c \quad \exists \overline{B}(x;r)\quad \text{s.t}\quad \overline{B}(x;r)\subseteq \mathcal{F}^c$

Comment: is this a correct approach @flan

Comment: Implying that $\mathcal{F}^c = \bigcup_{x\in\mathcal{F}^c}\overline{B}(x,t)$

Comment: What is $\overline{B}$, a closed ball? You should use $B$, open balls, as in the proof. Also the $t$ in your last comment depends on $x$. That is why they wrote $\delta_x$ in the proof.